# Enable gpu support by default on docker containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using a platform ([Cytomine](https://uliege.cytomine.org/)) on Ubuntu 18.04 to run some deep learning containerized applications (this platform handles the Docker images and containers automatically, so I only need to create the image and provide its download URL to the platform). So far it's working good but now I need to enable GPU support to run the model efficiently. Thus, I did some local tests with [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) to manually run the model container with GPU support, it was really easy to have it working because I just had to add one option to the run command:

`docker run --gpus all`

However, because I cannot add this option to the code on the [Cytomine](https://uliege.cytomine.org/) platform I need to find a way of adding/enabling that option by default to all the containers run by docker.

I tried adding this option to the files `/etc/docker/daemon.json and /etc/docker/key.json` and then restarted docker `sudo systemctl restart docker`. However, it didn't work.

Also, I found how to create docker config files ([docker config](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/config/)); however, this seems to work only with Docker Swarm and I'm not going to use a Swarm for this project.

Thus, I'm looking for a straightforward solution that can be deployed properly. Is there any way to enable this option (--gpus all) by default when running any Docker container? (like somehow including it on the Dockerfile?)

Thanks!